# Place divs next to each other in footer. How?

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm having a problem with placing my divs on the same line inside of my footer element. What happens is that one div is pushing down so the other places underneath it. Here is my html code:

```
<footer>
      <div class="footercontact">
        email@email.com<br />
        phone number<br />
        Street name Number<br />
        Postnumber
        </div>

        <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook logo" class="social-icon"></a>         

    <div id="clockdiv">
        <div class="dayItem clockItem"></div>
        <div class="hourItem clockItem"></div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS code:

```
footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px; 
}

.footercontact {
  text-align:left;
  width: 25%;
}

#clockdiv
{
    float: right;
}
```

So basically i want my first div, my anchor elements and the second div to all be next to each other in the footer. How do i acheive this? Thank you!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Sorry i just solved it, i thought i wrote float: left on the first div instead of text-align: left

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
}

footer > div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div style="background-color: red">Address</div>
  <div style="background-color: green">Links</div>
  <div style="background-color: blue">Clock</div>
</footer>
```